# WordPress Install Issue, Receive Warnings But Successful Install

Tags: customization, installation, microsoft

I get the following warning on my installation. It installs successfully but I'm not sure whether or not these issues are vital to my blog. I'm using IIS, anyone know why I'm having these issues and what I can do to get rid of these errors?

> Warning: unlink(C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\bozack/5505560414c7fd72a81f63.tmp) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\bozack\wp-admin\includes\misc.php on line 585
>
> Warning: unlink(C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\bozack/web.config) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\bozack\wp-admin\includes\misc.php on line 585

Answer (score 2):

To determine if a directory is writable or not, WordPress attempts to [create a temporary file](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.1/wp-admin/includes/misc.php#L559) with a random name and then immediately delete it. Your installation is allowing WordPress to create the files but not delete them. I don't know why not, so I can't help you with the error messages, but it's probably a permissions issue. The .tmp files won't hurt anything.